# Power set axiom in constructible Universe

Tags: logic, set-theory

For the power set axiom in L, I need that for an infinite ordinal $\alpha$ with $S\in L_\alpha$ there exists an ordinal $\beta$ such that $\mathscr{P}(S)\cap L \subseteq L_{\beta}$

I think that $\beta$ should have higher cardinality than $\alpha$ since sets of size $\alpha$ could be in A (I assume $\beta$ is just as big as the next higher cardinal). How do I show that such a $\beta$ exists? Do I need to look at $\mathscr{P}(S)\cap L $ in $V$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need to look at the set $\mathcal P(S)\cap L$. For each $x$ in this set, there is a unique smallest ordinal $\alpha$ such that $x\in L_\alpha$. The axiom of replacement gives us a set consisting of these smallest $\alpha$'s for all $x\in \mathcal P(S)\cap L$, and the supremum of this set of ordinals is the $\beta$ you need.

Comment: More generally, for **any** set (as opposed to class) $X$ there is some $\beta$ such that $X\cap L=X\cap L_\beta$.